# MySQL efficient test if count w/ where is greater than a value

Tags: mysql, count, query-optimization, where-clause, short-circuiting

Is there a way to optimize the following query?

```
SELECT count(*)>1000 FROM table_with_lot_of_rows WHERE condition_on_index;
```

Using this query, MySQL first performs the `count(*)` and then the comparison. This is is fast when only few rows satisfy the condition, but can take forever if a lot of rows satisfy it. Is there a way to stop counting as soon as 1000 items are found, instead of going through all the results?

In particular, I'm interested in MyISAM table with full-text condition, but any answer for InnoDB and/or basic WHERE clause will help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT 1
    FROM table_with_lot_of_rows
    WHERE condition_on_index
    LIMIT 1000, 1;
```

Works this way:

1. Using the index (which is presumably faster than using the data)
2. Skip over 1000 rows, collecting *nothing*.  (This is better than other answers.)
3. If you make it this far, fetch 1 row, containing only the literal `1` (in the `SELECT`).

Now you either have an empty result set (<= 1000 rows) or a row of `1` (at least 1001 rows).

Then, depending on your application language, it is easy to distinguish between the two cases.

Another note:  If this is to be a subquery in a bigger query, then do

```
EXISTS ( SELECT 1
    FROM table_with_lot_of_rows
    WHERE condition_on_index
    LIMIT 1000, 1 )
```

Which returns TRUE/FALSE (which are synonymous with 1 or 0).

Face it, scanning 1001 rows, even of the index, will take *some* time.  I think my formulation is the fastest possible.

Other things to check:  Is this InnoDB?  Does `EXPLAIN` say "Using index"?  How much RAM?  What is the setting of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?

Note that InnoDB now has FULLTEXT, so there is no reason to stick with MyISAM.

If you are using MyISAM and the `WHERE` is `MATCH...`, then most of what I said is likely not to be applicable.  `FULLTEXT` *probably* fetches all results before giving the rest of the engine to chance to do these games with `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`.

Please show us the actual query, its `EXPLAIN`, and `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  And what is the real goal?  To see if a query will deliver "too many" results?

**Possible improvement** (depending on context)

Since my initial `SELECT` returns scalar `1` or `NULL`, it can be used in any boolean context such as `WHERE`.  `1` is `TRUE`, `NULL` will be treated as `FALSE`.  Hence `EXISTS` is probably redundant.

Also, `1`/`NULL` can be turned into `1`/`0` thus.  Note: the extra parens are required.

```
IFNULL( ( SELECT ... LIMIT 1000,1 ), 0)
```

Comment: Great solution, thanks! Giving the details of my specific setting might be off-topic for this question, which was for improvement over the basic `count(*)>1000`, and not related to indexes.

Comment: `FULLTEXT`, `SPATIAL`, `PRIMARY`, and other indexes work in 4 different ways.

Comment: After I offered the bounty, I came up with a modified version of this that gets my desired "`0` or `1`" instead of "nothing or `1`" as the result, without repeating the threshold value (which violates DRY), but it's still subquery based (which feels ugly). I'll leave the bounty up to see if someone can do it without a subquery for style points, but otherwise, the bounty is yours for inspiring me. My modified version is just wrapping it to `COUNT` the results of your query: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT 1 FROM table_with_lot_of_rows WHERE condition_on_index LIMIT 1000, 1);`

Answer (score 1):

You can optimize the query using a sub-query with a LIMIT:

```
SELECT count(*)>1000 FROM (
    SELECT 0 table_with_lot_of_rows
    WHERE condition_on_index
    LIMIT 1001
) as truncated_count;
```

In that case, MySQL stops as soon as enough rows satisfy the condition.